# zerolog with stdout and file logger adds additional message field in the file

Tags: go, zerolog

I am using `zerolog` package in my go project and I need to log the content in both file as well as `stdout`. I took reference from [here](https://zerolog.io/#multiple-log-output). The only change I have made is, instead of creating new variable named `logger`, I am directly affecting the global logger.

```
runLogFile, _ := os.OpenFile(
        "myapp.log",
        os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY,
        0664,
    )
fileLogger := zerolog.New(runLogFile).With().Logger()
multi := zerolog.MultiLevelWriter(os.Stdout, fileLogger)
log.Logger = zerolog.New(multi).With().Timestamp().Logger()

log.Info().Msg("Hello World!")
```

It produces output in the stdout as shown below, which is expected.

```
{"level":"info","time":"2022-09-15T08:10:28-04:00","message":"Hello World!"}
```

But, the file content becomes messy with additional message field which wraps the above output again.

```
{"message":"{\"level\":\"info\",\"time\":\"2022-09-15T08:10:28-04:00\",\"message\":\"Hello World!\"}"}
```

How can I enforce the zerolog to log the content without additional message field ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MultiLevelWriter` accept `io.Writer`. So you can input `runLogFile` to this.

In the end, the code look like this :

```golang
runLogFile, _ := os.OpenFile(
        "myapp.log",
        os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY,
        0664,
    )
multi := zerolog.MultiLevelWriter(os.Stdout, runLogFile)
log.Logger = zerolog.New(multi).With().Timestamp().Logger()

log.Info().Msg("Hello World!")
```